# Global stylesheet isn't fully working

Tags: qt

I'm trying to set a global stylesheet for all my buttons.
Doing it for a specific button like the following, works as expected:

```
button->setStyleSheet(QString("QPushButton:focus {") +
                                  "outline: 0;" +
                                  "background-color: #" + BUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_BG_COLOR  + "; " +
                                  "color: #"            + BUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_TXT_COLOR + "; " +
                              "}"
                     );
```

But if I make it global, like this:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet(QString("QPushButton:focus {") +
                                  "outline: 0;" +
                                  "background-color: #" + BUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_BG_COLOR  + "; " +
                                  "color: #"            + BUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_TXT_COLOR + "; " +
                            "}"
                   );
```

the focused buttons get the correct font color, but they don't seem to have a background (although the background I'm setting for them is different from the main layout's background.)

`BUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_BG_COLOR` and `BUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_TXT_COLOR` are strings for colors (e.g. "FF0000")

What could be the cause that it works for a specific widget, but fails globally?

**update:**

I followed @ThorngardSO's answer and finally solved it by changing:

```
stackedWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");
```

to:

```
stackedWidget->setStyleSheet("QStackedWidget { background-color: white; }");
```

which was in the loading screen (first screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to narrow it down as much as possible:

- Is this the only rule in your global stylesheet? If not, remove all other rules for testing purposes and see what happens.
- Get a clear grasp on the widget-hierachy of your button (perhaps it's the child of a groupbox which is itself a child of a mainwindow), and then check:
- Do any of those widgets in the hierachy have a stylesheet set? If yes, remove those stylesheets for testing purposes and see what happens.
- Do you, at any time, call functions like `setPalette()` or `setAutoFillBackground()` on any of the widgets in the hierachy (or have the auto-fill-background property set in the designer)? If yes, remove those calls and see what happens.

Comment: 1. I had only 2 global rules, narrowed it down to 1, didn't help. 2. It is a child of a `groupbox`, which is a child of a mainwindow. 3. The `groupbox` itself had a stylesheet - I removed it, another child which is a `QLabel` had a stylesheet - removed it. Didn't help. 4. No. 5. What makes it strange for me is that it works on `button->setStylesheet...` but not on `qApp->setStylesheet`

Comment: It worked! I had a `stackedWidget->setStyleSheet` on the loading screen. I see where the problem is coming from now. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked out -- the cascading/inheriting of stylesheets can often lead to behaviour that seems quite strange at first.

Answer (score 2):

Not that it's your problem, but you're assembling that constant string at runtime from bits and pieces. Don't do that. Instead, you can simply concatenate string literals in C and C++ simply by putting them next to each other.

```
qApp->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral(
  "QPushButton:focus {"
    "outline: 0;"
    "background-color: #" BUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_BG_COLOR  "; "
    "color: #" BUTTON_HIGHLIGHT_TXT_COLOR "; "
  "}"
));
```

If you wanted the colors to be changeable at runtime, use the %-substitution:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral(
  "QPushButton:focus {"
    "outline: 0;"
    "background-color: #%1; "
    "color: #%2; "
  "}"
).arg(background).arg(foreground));
```

Comment: Even if i write `"background-color: red;"`, it doesn't work. Also note that `font-color` works.

Comment: Anyway, this is not an answer to the question... Should be a comment

Comment: @AlaaM If only comments could be that long :)